# "No quotas available" in brand new Azure subscription

Tags: azure

We have a brand new (as in, created a couple of days ago and no resources in it yet) Azure pay-as-you-go subscription, and now when I try to provision something, I'm not allowed.

Looking at the subscription in the portal, under "Usage + quotas" the list is empty.

Did we do something wrong when signing up? How do we enable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there were some things I could do myself on this, and some things I had to turn to Azure Support for.

### Thing I could do myself: Enable a bunch of resource providers

It turned out the subscription did not have a single resource provider enabled. To fix, I found the Subscription blade, and clicked the "Resource Providers" menu item (toward the bottom). That opened up a list where I could register lots of stuff. This also enabled corresponding quotas on the subscription.

### Thing I couldn't do myslef: Increase e.g. VM quotas

Some of those quotas, however, I wasn't able to figure out how to turn on myself. Crucially, one of them was for provisioning VM:s (including "hidden" ones, e.g. the underlying VM:s in an AKS cluster or an App Service). Thankfully, Azure Support were really responsive and from first contact until I was able to provision stuff took less than a business day.

Answer (score 5):

You only need to register to the *Microsoft.Compute* Resource Provider on the Subscriptions Blade.

- Go to Subscriptions
- Select the desired subscription
- Click on Resource Providers
- Register to the option *"Microsoft.Compute"*